# node:test in combination with Electron Forge Typescript project

Tags: typescript, electron-forge, node-test-runner

I am working on an Electron App created with the Electron Forge 'Webpack + Typescript' template project.

Everything is working fine but now I wanted to add unit-test using `node:test`.

I got my test working but only if i add `"type": "module",` to my `package.json`. Otherwise running the test says:

```
> {myproject}@0.0.1 test
> glob -c  "node --loader tsx --no-warnings --test" "tests/**/*.ts"

{myrepo}\tests\server-log\parse-lines.ts:1
  import assert from 'assert/strict';
  ^^^^^^

  SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

But when I then do `npm run start` to start the Electron app, I get:

```
✖ Loading configuration                                                                                                                              
  › Must use import to load ES Module: {myrepo}\forge.config.ts                   
  require() of ES…                                                                                                                                   
◼ Preparing native dependencies                                                                                                                      
◼ Running generateAssets hook                                                                                                                        

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: {myrepo}\forge.config.ts
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of {myrepo}\forge.config.ts from {myrepo}\node_modules\@electron-forge\core\dist\util\forge-config.js is an ES module file as it is a .ts file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .ts files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from {myrepo}\package.json.
```

So I tried many things, like change `"module"` in `tsconfig.json` / `compileOptions` to `"es2015"`, but could not get it to work.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "src/**/*.ext",
  ]
}
```

I run tests with `npm run test`:

```
    "test": "glob -c  \"node --loader tsx --no-warnings --test\" \"tests/**/*.ts\"",
```

## Update

So after reading this:
[Support Node's ES Modules #21457 1099904505](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21457#issuecomment-1099904505)
I realised that trying to make Electron work with ESM is just not an option.

So I tried this:

I renamed my test file so the extension is `.mts`. This seems to get me a step further, but then the problem becomes how to import the `.ts` file that has the function I want to test.

- using accolades in import seems to be the problem so i removed `{` and `}`
- this gives me `Module '"{myrepo}/src/server-log"' has no default export. Did you mean to use 'import { xyz } from "{myrepo}/src/server-log"' instead?`
- adding default to that function helps (`export default function`), but running the test gives me `^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

## Update 2

I thought I could make this work by running tsx with it's own `tsconfig.json`, or beginning the script with `cd scripts &&`  and then having a `package.json` in that folder with `"type": "module"` so the `--test` file(s) run with ESM settings....

Did not get it to work yet though....

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work eventually but using `ts-node` (<s>or more precisely `ts-node-script`</s> Don't know why i wrote this, `ts-node` works fine) instead of using `node --loader tsx ...`, or something like that.

Using `node --loader` and/or `tsx` put me in a maze of error messages like:
`TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`,
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`,
`module has no default export`,
`exports is not defined in ES module scope`,
`Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

All the suggestions I could find on how to solve these errors, included things I needed to change in my already existing Electron Forge Webpack & Typescript project, that would have severe consequences and/or break it.

#### My solution

I installed glob (`npm i glob --save-dev`), and ts-node (`npm i ts-node --save-dev`).

And added this to my scripts:

```
  "test": "glob -c \"ts-node\" \"./tests/**/*.ts\""
```

Comment: Can you link to the project where you're doing this, so I can see the various details?

Comment: No. It is a internal tool, with code in a company repo. What more details would you like to see?

Comment: Ok, it's surprisingly easy: add glob and ts-node, and the script and run it. Put the tests in a `tests` directory next to `src`. Test code can include the code to be tested using a relative path like, `import { logJson } from "../src/main/log";` or presumably via the `include` array you showed in `tsconfig.json` in the OP. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Using `glob` doesn't work well with VS Code for debugging -- presumably VS Code attaches to `glob` and not not the `ts-node` instances launched using `glob` -- instead I configure a script to run one specific unit-test, and launch VS Code to debug that.